# Codeigniter upload: return uploaded picture's url

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, image-uploading

I have a upload input, And I want to save the url into the database.

How can I get picture's url in codeigniter?

[Codeigniter file uploading](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) just return these:

```
[file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
[full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
```

I want to have link of image, like:

```
www.example.com/path/someWhere/picture.jpg
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you show any code you have made for this?

or what exactly is the problem in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `base_url()`.

```
$uploadData = $this->upload->data();

$fullPath = base_url() .'upload/'. $uploadData['file_name'];
```

Comment: Shouldn't be using full_path since it will contain the absolute file path which wouldn't be accessible via url.

Comment: @Samosa yes. This is the right answer. `base_url() . 'upload/' . $data_name['file_name'];` It seems very easy, Sorry about asking this question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the context but you should be doing something like this :-

First set the media_url in config.

$config['media_url'] = "http://example.com/media/path/"

Then in the upload script :-

```
$upload_data = $this->CI->upload->data();
return $this->CI->config->item('media_url').$upload_data['file_name'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But where should I set this `config['media_url']` ?

Comment: You can put it in application/config/config.php